# Angular 2 template disintegrating on route change: previous page attaching to desired page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I'm dealing with a particularly annoying problem right now. I'm just a begginer with Angular 2 and Javascript as a whole  but I'll try to explain my problem as coherently as possible.

The routing works fine, meaning I can navigate through the different pages well, it's just that whenever I change page, the previous page's template gets attached to the bottom of the actual required page.

Graphically:

*say this is the previous page, page A:*

---

**Page A**

feature 1,
feature 2,
feature 3

---

*and this is the page I want to navigate to now, page B:*

---

**Page B**

feature 4,
feature 5,
feature 6

---

I'd like to only see page B, but what I see instead is:

---

**Page B**

feature 4,
feature 5,
feature 6

---

**Page A**

feature 1,
feature 2,
feature 3

---

When I navigate to page C, then, I see on screen page **C, B and A**, and so on.

I have no idea what could be causing this issue, does anyone have any ideas on why that might be?

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**There's two nestled router-outlets in the application** (it's an Intranet admin panel). There's one at the root app module level and then another one at one level deep of nesting.

Basically:

```
app.module
app.component.html (first router-outlet)

|
|--  layout.module
     layout.component.html( second router-outlet)
     |  
     |-- (all the code for the various sections of the admin panel is here, nestled inside this second router-outlet)
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and then layout.component.html

```
 <app-header></app-header>
 <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
 <section class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </section>
```

Comment: can you show the component where you have put the `router outlet`

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have updated the post with the information you requested!